# Using sticky footer, can't get the background of main content to stretch to footer

Tags: css, footer, sticky

I've read a very similar post and tried all the solutions, and had no joy.  This is what I have. I have website with full width (100%) header and footer space and a smaller width container.  I used the Ryan Fait sticky footer but the container (with white background) does not reach down to the footer unless I just put in a bunch of line breaks, which defeats the purpose of the sticky footer.

Styles:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;}

body    {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
overflow-y: scroll;}

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -30px;}

.container {
width:1050px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
padding:0 25px 0 25px;
background-color:#FFF;
    }

 .footer, .push {
height: 30px;}

 .footer {
background-color:#000;
width:100%;
height: 30px;}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
/* content */
</div>
<!--end container-->
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
<div class="footer">
/* footer */
</div>
<!--end footer-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just get rid of `.wrapper` and move `.push` into your `.container`

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32WxJ/3/